# chrome.windows.update doesn't work correctly on ubuntu (17.04 MATE)

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome-extension, window

I'm writing an chrome extension for changing window size with `chrome.windows.update`, and it works fine on Windows 10 when called like this:

```
chrome.windows.update(windowId, {width:500,height:300});
```

but on Ubuntu 17.04 MATE it changes size to 500x300 just for a moment (almost unnoticeable) and reverts to the original size.

What could be a problem, shouldn't Chrome APIs be OS independent?

Comment: Either that or your desktop window manager resizes it.

Comment: Either what? :D

Comment: OS dependent :-)